# Context free grammar modification for simple arithmetic Expression

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, computation-theory

given a CFG

```
E->TE'
E'->+TE'|-TE'|null
T->FT'
T'->*FT'|/FT'|null
F->(E)|number
```

how to implement this CFG in C Program so that it take multiple digit  input in expression.for Example - i want to give  320/40-12*2+1*32   as input in the above CFG converted code.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you use `regex`?

Comment: @meaning-matters: You could, but using a CFG would give a parse tree useful to the compiler while a regex would not.

Comment: From how the grammar is structured, I assume you want an LL(1) grammar?

Answer (score 0):

Add the rules:

```
number -> digit | digit number
digit -> 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

Now write a parser in C.  Since this is a trivial LL(1) grammar, the easiest way to do that is with recursive descent -- write a function for each non-terminal in the grammar that recognizes that non-terminal on your input and consumes it.